# BIRT 4.3.1 runtime compatibility with PDFBox jar

Tags: birt, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox jar to print the pdf generated from my BIRT module. 
BIRT version is 4.3.1 which i am planning  to upgrade.
I just wanted to know that BIRT uses PDFBox or IText internally to generate the PDF.
If i use PDFBox with BIRT 4.3.1 do i have to worry that it might cause issues with BIRT PDF generation if BIRT is using some other version of PDFBox jar internally.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I've heard that birt uses iText to generate pdf. Just test it. It's the saves way to get this sure if it really works.